# How to publish content in Django from a python script?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have a script in python and I also have an installation of Django 1.10 and Django REST framework.

With the script in Python I would like to authenticate and then send content from my content types.

How is the best way to do this?

My models are as follows:

```
# Model of Reports
class Report(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

# Model of Invoices
class Invoice(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    emision_date = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    re = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    rr = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    type_invoice = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.uuid
```

I think maybe send by json user and password, but how do I get a token ?, how do I send my content and the token? Those are my doubts

Comment: Is this a external script or runs within project? Do you have token based authentication setup for authenticating user profile ?

Comment: It is a script external to Django written in Python 3, it runs on the local user's computer and Django is remote on a server @BipulJain

Comment: I do not know what kind of authentication suits me better, if user and password or token, or to use in this case

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [django-oauth-toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit) for token authentication and [request](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) for HTTP requests.

[Here](https://yeti.co/blog/oauth2-with-django-rest-framework/) you can find more information.